# alpakka: stream objects from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, akka-stream, alpakka

Is there a way to read all objects from given s3 bucket as s3 Source with alpakka ?
I need something like this (pseudocode):

```
S3.readObjects(bucket)
  .map(object => parseJson(object.getContent))
  ...
```

There are two sources provided by alpakka s3 integration: `S3.listBucket(bucket)` and `S3.download(bucket, key)` but I failed to combine those 2 together to achieve desired behaviour. I'm completely new to akka streams, should I combine those two or is there other way ?

I'm using akka-stream 2.5.31 and alpakka 2.0.0

Comment: I don't fully understand the return type of `S3.download` so I am not able to produce a correct code snippet but generally `flatMapConcat` is what you need to flatten multiple `Source`s into one

Comment: thanks for the answer, at the moment I come up with using just ordinary s3 client for downloading object as a Flow. Will look into `flatMapConcat`